# Mongoose - Count subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to count subdocuments of the main document. Just an example of scheme:

Model:

```
{
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    comments: [{
        comment: {type: String, required: true},
        author: {type: String, required: true}
    }]
}
```

This query doesn't work:

```
Model.findById(ObjectId).count('comments', function(err, res) { 
    if (err) { throw err; } 
    else { console.log(res); } 
});
```

How can I count comments in some document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `.length`

```
Model.findById(ObjectId, function(err, res) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    if (!res) { console.log('model not found'); }
    console.log(res.comments.length);
};
```